# Specifying a default value for a setter method

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code:

```
class Dummy
  def attr=(arg = 10)
    @attr = arg
  end
  def attr2=(arg = 20)
    @attr2 = 20
  end
end;
d = Dummy.new; d.attr=(); d.attr2=(); d
=> #<Dummy:0x007f8d6430e2a8 @attr=nil, @attr2=20>
```

It seems the `attr=` method discards the default parameter value and assigns `nil` to the instance variable anyway, yet assigning an explicit value works in the `attr2=` method. Why is this happening?

### Edit:

I should have expressed myself in a more clear way. Assigning an explicit value obviously works in the `attr2=` method. That leaves only one explanation - the setter methods discard the default parameter value. Why is this discarding happening?

Comment: It works for `attr2` because you _always_ set it to `20`: `@attr2 = 20`...

Comment: Get a cup of coffee man while programming!! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods ending with `=` are not ordinary methods, as they are identified by ruby interpreter as setters, and hence have syntactic sugar:

```
d.attr = 4
```

When you are calling `d.attr=()`, you are actually calling `d.attr=(())`. `()` in ruby returns `nil`:

```
()
# => nil
```

Ruby interpreter will not let you get away with not having any arguments, because if you drop the `()` altogether, ruby will simply take the result of the next line as parameter, or throw a `syntax error` if you try to break the line using `;`

```
d.attr=
  5
# => 5

d.attr=;
# => syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

To see your default argument at work, you can use `send`:

```
d.send(:attr=)
# => 10
d
# => #<Dummy:0x007f8d6430e2a8 @attr=10, @attr2=20>
```

Comment: So the `()` part is considered as an argument, as an rvalue and not as a "method invocation", am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are not setting the value of the instance variable using the default argument - `arg` in the setter `attr2`. You are hard coding the value 20 in the method, thats why it gets set while the setter `attr` is not.

Having said that, I believe you can't leave out arguments in a method that ends in equal in Ruby and expect to pass nothing; I believe nil will be passed with no argument is available.

Comment: True, my bad. I wasn't sure about the reasoning behind though I was quite certain about what I thought. I should have refrained from posting it. Perhaps, I shouldn't be deleting it as people might get benefited from this discussion why its a bad answer?

Answer (score 0):

Nice explanation by @Uri Agassi. But I guess we don't need to use **send** here. we can do the following :-

```
class Dummy
  def attr=(arg)
    #assign default value here
    arg = 10 if arg.nil? 
    @attr = arg
  end
  def attr2=(arg = 20)
    @attr2 = 20
  end
end;
d = Dummy.new; d.attr=(); d.attr2=(); p d
```

Comment: Default parameter value does not substitute `nil`:

    d.send(:attr=, nil); d
    => #<Dummy:0x007f8d668f8ef0 @attr=nil, @attr2=20>

While this approach does.

Comment: true, its just a work around in case you want d.attr=() to work, or else d.send(:attr=) or d.public_send(:attr=) should work fine :) - as already higlighted

Comment: Its my bad, my piece of code should fail for nil. for rest cases it should work fine, but yes its not the standard behavior, just a workaround

Comment: You could also write `@attr = arg || 10`.